# Etherscan API: understanding the results of the `txlist` action of the `account` module

Tags: blockchain, transactions, etherscan

I want to make sure I understand the return values for the `txlist` action in the `account` module, which is [documented here](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address).

There is a `txreceipt_status` field in the return value, which I assume means that there is no need to call the separate `gettxreceiptstatus` on the `transaction` module in order to check the receipt status for that transaction, is this correct? If so, this also means that a transaction will show up in the `txlist` results only after it’s been fully handled and completed, i.e. ending either in a success or in an error?